# Dart - How to destructure a record in method parameters?

Tags: dart

I have this method:

```dart
void myMethod((String, int) record) {
  final (s, i) = record;
  // ...
}
```

I would like to destructure the record in the method parameters directly. For example, something like:

```dart
void myMethod((String, int) (s, i)) {
  // ...
}
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible right now in Dart 3.0, but it is something that is being discussed on the Dart language issue tracker as an suggestion for improvement: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/3001